# Rowspan h ref entire spanned cell clickable link

Tags: html, css, html-table, href

I have a table which has spanned rows. When I create an h ref the link is only clickable on the one line I would like to have the link clickable anywhere on that cell.

I've tried the following:

`<table>
<tr><td rowspan=2><a style='display:block; width:100%; height:100%;' href='#'</td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell 4</td><td>Cell 5</td></tr>
</table>`

`<table>
<tr><td rowspan=2><a style='display:inline-block; width:100%; height:100%;' href='#'</td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell 4</td><td>Cell 5</td></tr>
</table>`

Is there a way of getting the link to span both rows?

Answer (score 1):

your html syntax seems incorrect as your  tag isn't properly ended. You could try this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td rowspan="2">
          <a style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%;" href="#">Text in your big cell 1</a>
       </td>
       <td>Cell 2</td>
       <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Cell 4</td>
       <td>Cell 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, you will better see such problems with nicer indentation ;-)